# How to show a XAML element in full screen when the page orientation is changed?

Tags: windows, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-rt

In my Windows Phone 8.1 RT app, I have an image inside pivot control.

I want to show the element in full screen when the page orientation is changed to vertical.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My XAML is as shown below.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
    <Pivot Title="{Binding ItemTitle}">
        <PivotItem Header="Overview">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image x:Name="MainImage" Source="{Binding ImageURL}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="TitleTextBlock" Text={Binding Title}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="Details">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <TextBlock x:Name="DetailsTextBlock" Text="{Binding Details}"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

I'm trying to show the image control `MainImage` in full screen when the page orientation changed to Landscape and revert it back to normal Pivot when the orientation changes back to 
Portrait.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot expand the pivot view content to full so that it hold the full area. one solution is use a separate image control and make it hidden and on orientation change show this image and hide grid vice verse for portrait view. here is how

Your page Xaml

```
<Grid Name="MainPage">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OrientationManager">
            <VisualState x:Name="Portrate">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPanel">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible">
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="MainImage1">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed">
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPanel">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed">
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="MainImage1">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible">
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
        <Pivot Title="{Binding ItemTitle}">
            <PivotItem Header="Overview">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Image x:Name="MainImage" Source="{Binding ImageURL}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="TitleTextBlock" Text="asfsadf"/>
        </StackPanel>
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem Header="Details">
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="DetailsTextBlock" Text="{Binding Details}"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
    </Grid>
    <Image Source="Assets\WideLogo.scale-14012.png" Visibility="Collapsed" Name="MainImage1"></Image>
</Grid>
```

*Make sure that `VisualStateManager` element is in the root control/Grid of the page*

Code in your page constructor.

```
 DisplayInformation di =  DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
        di.OrientationChanged += di_OrientationChanged;

        if (di.CurrentOrientation == DisplayOrientations.Landscape || di.CurrentOrientation == DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Landscape", true);
        }
        else
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Portrate", true);

        }
```

Orientation changed event handler

```
 void di_OrientationChanged(DisplayInformation sender, object args)
    {
        if (sender.CurrentOrientation == DisplayOrientations.Landscape || sender.CurrentOrientation == DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Landscape", true);
        }
        else
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Portrate", true);

        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

```
<Grid Name="MainPage">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OrientationManager">
            <VisualState x:Name="Portrate">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PivotHeaderText1">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible">
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PivotHeaderText2">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible">
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>

            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PivotHeaderText1">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed">
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PivotHeaderText2">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed">
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
        <Pivot Title="{Binding ItemTitle}">
            <PivotItem>
                <PivotItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Overview" x:Name="PivotHeaderText1" ></TextBlock>
                </PivotItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <MediaElement AutoPlay="True" x:Name="player" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="TitleTextBlock" Text="asfsadf"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem>
                <PivotItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Overview" x:Name="PivotHeaderText2" ></TextBlock>
                </PivotItem.Header>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="DetailsTextBlock" Text="{Binding Details}"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is there any way to do it with the same element? For example, I may have a Media Player control there instead of the Image. So I wouldn't want two different media players running at the same time and hogging the memory.

Comment: only change the page xaml